# How to power on Murata D1U-2000-48-HB4C without plug in

Tags: power-supply

Hi guys i'm trying to power on murata AC to DC D1U-2000-48-HB4C model.
i have tried connecting PS_On and PS_Kill to ground since in datasheet stated that ps_on and ps_kill need to be pulled out but still failed to power on the psu. please advice..

[image: Datasheet]

Datasheet link: https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/products/power/datasheet/cps_d1u-2000-48-hx.ashx?la=ja-jp

Thank You

Comment: Advice : start debugging. There's an AC_OK output. Is it doing the right thing? Theer's a standby supply. Is it doing the right thing? There's an I2C interface (presumably it can talk to a MCU powered from  Standby)  Does the datasheet mention anything you need to do with  tI2C to start the supply? Can you get diagnostics out of it?

Comment: Thank you for the advice brian.. but if i cant figure out how to turn on the power supply its no point in debugging the ac_ok.. This is a good working power supply.. i'm trying to figure out how to turn it on without actually slotted it in the rack.. because i need the output to do something else..